# How to have QFileSelector select files based on device

Tags: qt, qml

Reading the [QFileSelector Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileselector.html) documentation, I see:

> QFileSelector is a convenience for selecting file variants based on platform or device characteristics

I am successfully using the related [QQmlFileSelector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlfileselector.html) class to select a set of files based on if I am building for Mac (a `+mac` directory).

However, I need to also build for Ubuntu Desktop and an embedded device which is also running Ubuntu. Therefore, I cannot just add another platform directory directly related to ubuntu.

Based on the reference to `device characteristics` in the documentation, I figure I can create a folder directly related to the device.

I have a Kit setup for the embedded device and a Device used by the kit named Ansible.

Can anyone provide further details on how I can have QQmlFileSelector select the files in a *+* folder when building for Ansible?

Comment: You can add your own selectors using any name you want.

Comment: What, exactly, is meant by "device characteristics"? What pre-defined selectors are based on those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own selectors using any name you want. Here's an example:

```
    QQmlFileSelector *selector = QQmlFileSelector::get(engine);
    QStringList options;

    if (usingAnsible())
    {
        options << "ansible";
    }
    else
    {
        options << "x86";
    }

    selector->setExtraSelectors(options);
```

Then your files would be in either the `+ansible` or `+x86` directory.

Comment: How can I get Qt to then select files in +ansible? I assume that just because I have told the system that the selector is available that something else needs to happen to have it selected.

Comment: No, nothing else needs to happen. Whatever strings you add to the selectors list are what it will look for.